# Is there a way I can exit proc or function in mozart oz

Tags: oz, mozart

I am trying to do a recursion proc in mozart oz, is there a way I can exit the proc or function when I get my answer so that the rest recursion will not continue.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use an [exception](https://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/tutorial/node5.html#control.exception) for that.

But usually, the recursive call is at the end of a function anyway. Just returning will automatically go up the stack.

Comment: is there a return or something in oz, in proc you usually do not return anything, which is why I am asking about how to end the proc